# Audio production related questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Does digital audio related questions belong here?
If I'd ask a question that has nothing to do with video but focusing on audio only (mainly software-side), would be that marked as 'off-topic'?

Should these kind of questions go to Superuser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No and No.  Sound related to video is on topic here.  Sound that is purely sound related would go on [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com) as long as it is production rather than consumption oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Audio for specifically for music production is also usually on-topic at [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/).